# Sumar la diagonal de la matriz

Tags: c#

Tengo una matriz y se sacar la diagonal, pero no me suman los valores que hay, ¿me podrian ayudar por favor? este es mi codigo:

```
        int i,j, filas=0, columnas=0,sumadiagonal=0;
        Console.WriteLine("filas?");
        filas = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("columnas?");
        columnas = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        int[,] matriz=new int [filas, columnas];
        for (i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                matriz[i, j] = aleatorio.Next(0, 10);
                //Console.WriteLine("Ingrese numero en la posicion {0},{1}",i.ToString(),j.ToString());
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("MATRIZ");
        for (i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(matriz[i,j].ToString()+" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Diagonal");
        for (i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (i==j)
                {
                    Console.Write(matriz[i, j].ToString()+" ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("La suma de la diagonal es: ");
        for (i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    //sumadiagonal =matriz[i,j] + matriz[i,j];
                    Console.Write(matriz[i, j].ToString() + " ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Recuerda que el valor de la variable `filas`es igual a `matriz.GetLength(0)` y `columnas` es igual a `matriz.GetLength(1)`, es decir, podrías reemplazarlos en tu código (al momento de evaluarlo en los _for_) sin tener error alguno.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si comparas `i==j` entonces estos seran **0==0**, **1==1**, **2==2**, **...**, entonces lo mas eficas es:

```
Console.WriteLine("La suma de la diagonal es: ");
for (i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0) && i < matriz.GetLength(1); i++)
{
   sumadiagonal += matriz[i,i];
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write(sumadiagonal);
```

Comment: No entiendo porque el -1 si el algoritmo es mas eficas

Comment: Muchas gracias , funcionó perfectamente , pero no me es aun muy claro la posicion i,i  ya que entiendo que con la i recorro las filas y la j las columnas

Comment: Tu código solo funcionaría cuando es simétrico, en otros casos arrojaría la excepción `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Puedes revisar: https://dotnetfiddle.net/T4HHCZ

Comment: Davlio, tiene razón esta respuesta es incorrecta. Si la dimensíon 1 es mayor que la dimensión 0, `i` se saldrá del arreglo en la dimensión 0.

Comment: tienen razon la solucion ya fue editada

Comment: amigo este tipo que pregunta recien esta aprendiendo a programar, la pregunta es clara, el solo quiere sumar la diagonal de la matriz, es cierto que es as eficiente porque recorres menos pero al menos explicale porque haces eso, lo que a nosotros es evidente, quiza para el no ya que recien se esta metiendo en esto, yo te di -1 porque no explicas nada de esto, de frente estas suponiendo que el ya sabe pero no es asi. si la pregunta fuese el metodo mas eficiente para sacar la diagonal de una matriz pues yo hubiera usado recursividad y con un return y operadores ternarios lo hacia mas eficiente.

Answer (score 4):

La repuesta correcta en caso de que la matriz pudiera o no ser cuadrada, es decir si el número de filas es diferente al número de columnas sería:

```
Console.WriteLine("La suma de la diagonal es: ");
var indiceMáximo = Math.Min(filas , columnas);
for (var i = 0; i < indiceMáximo; i++)
{
    sumadiagonal += matriz[i, i];
}

Console.Write(sumadiagonal);
```

Debes iterar solo hasta el mínimo entre las dimensiones para que los índices no se salgan del arreglo como menciona Davlio en su comentario.

O si deseas, una forma de resolverlo en una sola línea :)

```
Console.WriteLine($"La suma de la diagonal es: {Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(filas, columnas)).Sum(x=> matriz[x, x])}");
```

Comment: me gusta como solucion.. de histerico solamente, no conviene reemplazar Math.Min(matriz.GetLength(0), matriz.GetLength(1)  por una variable que calcule eso antes del for? si no son 3 llamadas a cada funcion de esas por vuelta, sin sentido.. no es que cambia mucho..

Comment: @gbianchi, ya lo cambié a pedido tuyo

Comment: @gbianchi en todo caso, debería considerar solo las variables `filas` y `columnas`, por ejemplo: `Math.Min(filas, columnas)`.

Comment: mucho mejor! no habia mirado el codigo original... ;)

Comment: Listo @Davlio. Algún otro pedido?

Comment: Ya que estamos en esto podría convertirse en un oneliner, pero creo que ya sería abusar mucho

Comment: No me pude resistir a agregarla :)

Comment: No, @Renato A., Primero observe el comentario de Davlio, en otra respuesta,  luego elaboré la mía. Luego añadí las sugerencias de gbianchi y Davlio y finalmente agregué una opción más abajo de la anterior. La legibilidad de la respuesta adicional, es discutible, la expresión puede ser convertida en una función en una librería de matrices y ser totalmente legible, para alguien acostumbrado a operaciones matemáticas con matrices.